# iPhone, Keyboard with @ and # that also have English charcters

Tags: iphone, keyboard, development-environment

I would like to set to following keyboard for iPhone like in the screen shot.

What important for me is having English characters, '@' and '#' simultaneously.

[image: Screen shot of what I'm looking for]

Comment: So whats the problem in doing that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set keyboard type of textfield

```
    textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeTwitter;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Couldn't find this type because I was working with the interface builder, and seems it wasn't up to date.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation tells all.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006896-CH3-SW22) `UIKeyboardTypeTwitter`.

Comment: You may want to add that its available in ios 5.0 and above. Yeah yeah, the documentation tells all :-).